# Error in Lucene text Search

Tags: java, lucene, text-search

I'm new to text search and I'm studying some examples related to lucene. I found one of the example from this link. http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/ I tried it in my eclipse IDE. But it gives some errors. I imported all the relevent jar files as well.

Here Is the code :

> > public class InMemoryExample {
> >
> > ```
> > public static void main(String[] args) {
> >       // Construct a RAMDirectory to hold the in-memory representation
> >       // of the index.
> >        RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory();
> >
> >       try {
> >          // Make an writer to create the index
> >          IndexWriter writer =
> >                  new IndexWriter(idx, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48),
> > ```
> >
> > IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
> >
> > ```
> >          // Add some Document objects containing quotes
> >          writer.addDocument(createDocument("Theodore Roosevelt",
> >                  "It behooves every man to remember that the work of the " +
> >                          "critic, is of altogether secondary importance, and that, " +
> >                          "in the end, progress is accomplished by the man who does " +
> >                          "things."));
> >          writer.addDocument(createDocument("Friedrich Hayek",
> >                  "The case for individual freedom rests largely on the " +
> >                          "recognition of the inevitable and universal ignorance " +
> >                          "of all of us concerning a great many of the factors on " +
> >                          "which the achievements of our ends and welfare depend."));
> >          writer.addDocument(createDocument("Ayn Rand",
> >                  "There is nothing to take a man's freedom away from " +
> >                          "him, save other men. To be free, a man must be free " +
> >                          "of his brothers."));
> >          writer.addDocument(createDocument("Mohandas Gandhi",
> >                  "Freedom is not worth having if it does not connote " +
> >                          "freedom to err."));
> >
> >          // Optimize and close the writer to finish building the index
> >          writer.optimize();
> >          writer.close();
> >
> >          // Build an IndexSearcher using the in-memory index
> >          Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(idx);
> >
> >          // Run some queries
> >          search(searcher, "freedom");
> >          search(searcher, "free");
> >          search(searcher, "progress or achievements");
> >
> >          searcher.close();
> >       }
> >       catch (IOException ioe) {
> >          // In this example we aren't really doing an I/O, so this
> >          // exception should never actually be thrown.
> >          ioe.printStackTrace();
> >       }
> >       catch (ParseException pe) {
> >          pe.printStackTrace();
> >       }
> >    }
> >
> >    /**
> >     * Make a Document object with an un-indexed title field and an
> >     * indexed content field.
> >     */
> >    private static Document createDocument(String title, String content) {
> >       Document doc = new Document();
> >
> >       // Add the title as an unindexed field...
> >
> >       doc.add(new Field("title", title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
> >
> >
> >       // ...and the content as an indexed field. Note that indexed
> >       // Text fields are constructed using a Reader. Lucene can read
> >       // and index very large chunks of text, without storing the
> >       // entire content verbatim in the index. In this example we
> >       // can just wrap the content string in a StringReader.
> >       doc.add(new Field("content", content, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
> >
> >       return doc;
> >    }
> >
> >    /**
> >     * Searches for the given string in the "content" field
> >     */
> >    private static void search(Searcher searcher, String queryString)
> >            throws ParseException, IOException {
> >
> >       // Build a Query object
> >       //Query query = QueryParser.parse(
> >       QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("content", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48));
> >       Query query = parser.parse(queryString);
> >
> >
> >       int hitsPerPage = 10;
> >       // Search for the query
> >       TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(5 * hitsPerPage, false);
> >       searcher.search(query, collector);
> >
> >       ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
> >
> >       int hitCount = collector.getTotalHits();
> >       System.out.println(hitCount + " total matching documents");
> >
> >       // Examine the Hits object to see if there were any matches
> >
> >       if (hitCount == 0) {
> >          System.out.println(
> >                  "No matches were found for \"" + queryString + "\"");
> >       } else {
> >          System.out.println("Hits for \"" +
> >                  queryString + "\" were found in quotes by:");
> >
> >          // Iterate over the Documents in the Hits object
> >          for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++) {
> >             // Document doc = hits.doc(i);
> >             ScoreDoc scoreDoc = hits[i];
> >             int docId = scoreDoc.doc;
> >             float docScore = scoreDoc.score;
> >             System.out.println("docId: " + docId + "\t" + "docScore: " + docScore);
> >
> >             Document doc = searcher.doc(docId);
> >
> >             // Print the value that we stored in the "title" field. Note
> >             // that this Field was not indexed, but (unlike the
> >             // "contents" field) was stored verbatim and can be
> >             // retrieved.
> >             System.out.println("  " + (i + 1) + ". " + doc.get("title"));
> >             System.out.println("Content: " + doc.get("content"));            
> >          }
> >       }
> >       System.out.println();
> >    } }
> > ```

but it shows few syntax errors in following lines :

Error 1:

> IndexWriter writer = underline MaxFieldLength in red
>                      new IndexWriter(idx, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48),
>   IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);

Error 2: underline optimeze() in red

> writer.optimize();

Error 3: underline new IndexSearcher(idx) in red

> Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(idx);

Error 4: underline search in red

> searcher.search(query, collector);

Could you please help me to get rid of these errors? It will be a great help. Thanks

Modified code:

> public class InMemoryExample {
>
> public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
>           // Construct a RAMDirectory to hold the in-memory representation
>           // of the index.
>           RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory();
>
> ```
>        // Make an writer to create the index
>     IndexWriterConfig cfg = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_48, new
> ```
>
> StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48));
>           IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(idx, cfg);
>
> ```
>        // Add some Document objects containing quotes
>        writer.addDocument(createDocument("Theodore Roosevelt",
>                "It behooves every man to remember that the work of the " +
>                        "critic, is of altogether secondary importance, and that, " +
>                        "in the end, progress is accomplished by the man who does " +
>                        "things."));
>        writer.addDocument(createDocument("Friedrich Hayek",
>                "The case for individual freedom rests largely on the " +
>                        "recognition of the inevitable and universal ignorance " +
>                        "of all of us concerning a great many of the factors on " +
>                        "which the achievements of our ends and welfare depend."));
>        writer.addDocument(createDocument("Ayn Rand",
>                "There is nothing to take a man's freedom away from " +
>                        "him, save other men. To be free, a man must be free " +
>                        "of his brothers."));
>        writer.addDocument(createDocument("Mohandas Gandhi",
>                "Freedom is not worth having if it does not connote " +
>                        "freedom to err."));
>
>        // Optimize and close the writer to finish building the index
>        writer.commit();
>        writer.close();
>
>        // Build an IndexSearcher using the in-memory index
>        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(idx));
>
>        // Run some queries
>        search(searcher, "freedom");
>        search(searcher, "free");
>        search(searcher, "progress or achievements");
>
>        //searcher.close();
>
>
>
>  }
>
>  /**
>   * Make a Document object with an un-indexed title field and an
>   * indexed content field.
>   */
>  private static Document createDocument(String title, String content) {
>     Document doc = new Document();
>
>     // Add the title as an unindexed field...
>
>     doc.add(new Field("title", title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
>
>
>     // ...and the content as an indexed field. Note that indexed
>     // Text fields are constructed using a Reader. Lucene can read
>     // and index very large chunks of text, without storing the
>     // entire content verbatim in the index. In this example we
>     // can just wrap the content string in a StringReader.
>     doc.add(new Field("content", content, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
>
>     return doc;
>  }
>
>  /**
>   * Searches for the given string in the "content" field
>   */
>  private static void search(IndexSearcher searcher, String queryString)
>          throws ParseException, IOException {
>
>     // Build a Query object
>     //Query query = QueryParser.parse(
>     QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("content", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48));
>     Query query = parser.parse(queryString);
>
>
>     int hitsPerPage = 10;
>     // Search for the query
>     TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(5 * hitsPerPage, false);
>     searcher.search(query, collector);
>
>     ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
>
>     int hitCount = collector.getTotalHits();
>     System.out.println(hitCount + " total matching documents");
>
>     // Examine the Hits object to see if there were any matches
>
>     if (hitCount == 0) {
>        System.out.println(
>                "No matches were found for \"" + queryString + "\"");
>     } else {
>        System.out.println("Hits for \"" +
>                queryString + "\" were found in quotes by:");
>
>        // Iterate over the Documents in the Hits object
>        for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++) {
>           // Document doc = hits.doc(i);
>           ScoreDoc scoreDoc = hits[i];
>           int docId = scoreDoc.doc;
>           float docScore = scoreDoc.score;
>           System.out.println("docId: " + docId + "\t" + "docScore: " + docScore);
>
>           Document doc = searcher.doc(docId);
>
>           // Print the value that we stored in the "title" field. Note
>           // that this Field was not indexed, but (unlike the
>           // "contents" field) was stored verbatim and can be
>           // retrieved.
>           System.out.println("  " + (i + 1) + ". " + doc.get("title"));
>           System.out.println("Content: " + doc.get("content"));            
>        }
>     }
>     System.out.println();
>  } }
> ```

and this is the output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class
>   org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer overrides final method
>   tokenStream.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream;
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   beehex.inmemeory.textsearch.InMemoryExample.search(InMemoryExample.java:98)
>     at
>   beehex.inmemeory.textsearch.InMemoryExample.main(InMemoryExample.java:58)

Comment: what version of lucene are you using?

Comment: I'm using Lucene 4.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a third argument on the `IndexWriter` constructor. You should modify The code to fit to the new lucene api like so :

```
IndexWriterConfig cfg = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_48, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48));
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(idx, cfg);
```

Also , rather than catching an exception here , i'd rather make my `main` method throw `Exception` and let the program fail altogether

EDIT :

2) remove the `optimize` call as the `IndexWriter` class does not have that method any longer (i think `commit` will do the trick here) .

3) define the `IndexSearcher` class like so :

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(idx));
```

Comment: I remove the try-catch block and throws an exception. I modified the code as you mentioned. But I'm still getting 2nd ,3rd  and 4th syntax errors mentioned in my post.

Comment: give it a shot now . Also read this for future references : http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description

Comment: ugh.....You can't close the searcher, so delete that line. Actually just go to the link i pointed you to....and read some java tutorials while at it...

Comment: Did the modifications. Got an error in searcher.close();  Then I commented it and run the code. My output was in the initial post. It gives an error. I have posted the modified code again and the output. Sorry for the inconvenience happened. Really appreciate your support. Thanks a lot. Please help me to sort out this problem.